# How to send jSON in a url and later on deserialize it and format it in swift

Tags: json, swift, deserialization, json-deserialization

so am sending a request from my swift app using ASWebAuthenticationSession to this link ->

https://webcode.tools/generators/html/hyperlink

afterwards, on opening the website, I enter my callback URL in the URL field provided on the site ->
this is the callback URL am sending -

```
myApp://home/redirect?status=Wow-2023&code=200&data={\n \"name\": \"ios\",\n \"age\": 10,\n }
```

so in the status I had to send a string,
in the code I had to send an Int,
and in the data I had to send a JSON String

and then I click on " Click Here " under Preview section of the website and i have added the URLScheme so my app opens up and i receive the callback URL but now it's changed .
the URL returned to me is -

```
myApp://home/redirect?status=Wow-2023&code=200&data=%7B%5Cn%20%5C
```

now i have to show the status the code and the json deserialized and formatted in an alert box, the status and code is done but i don't get the JSON object out from this string of data, i have tried all this -

```
func nsdataToJSON(data: Data) -> AnyObject? {
    do {
        return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as AnyObject
    } catch let myJSONError {
        print(myJSONError)
    }
    return nil
}
```

this returns nil

```
            guard let decoded = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Person.self, from: Data(dataString.utf8)) else {
            print("AD:: we returned")
            return

        }
```

this also returns and I don't get any value what am I doing wrong here please help, am I not sending the right JSON in the URL field on the website?

Comment: `myApp://home/redirect?status=Wow-2023&code=200&data=%7B%5Cn%20%5C` that's more URL components, or URL encoding that JSON, so that's why it's not working. Side note `data={\n \"name\": \"ios\",\n \"age\": 10,\n }` is strange, why do you send the `"\n"` and the spaces? What is sent back is `{\\n \\`, so it's only the start of what you sent? But do you really need to send JSON?

Comment: Note that `JSONSerialization.jsonObject` return `Any` and not `AnyObject`.

Comment: @Larme basically i can send any json for now, what should I rather send then ?  is this better - myApp://home/redirect?status=Wow-2023&code=200&data={"id":38,"name":"Festival 2"}   ??

Comment: You are adding query parameters to your URL. You are not supposed to send JSON data in query parameters. You should almost certainly be sending a POST command with the JSON as the payload.

Comment: @DuncanC am aware of that, but for this task it has to be done this way only

Comment: With the current code you've shown it's only partial JSON as said. You can use URLComponents and QueryItems to retrieve each part (value & key): status, data, etc and they should be percent escaped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think passing JSON data in query parameters is a good idea, and it may not work, especially if your JSON data is very long.

In order to get it to work you will need to apply the correct encoding to the query parameters. By far the easiest and safest way to do that is to use an instance of `URLComponents`. Try using code like this to build your URL:

```
var compnonents = URLComponents()
guard let url = URL(string: "myApp://home/redirect"),
      var components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false) else {
    fatalError("splat!")
}
let query1 = URLQueryItem(name: "Status", value: "Wow")
let query2 = URLQueryItem(name: "code", value: "200")
let query3 = URLQueryItem(name: "data", value: "{\n \"name\": \"ios\",\n \"age\": 10,\n }")
components.queryItems = [query1, query2, query3]

if let urlString = components.string {
    print("URL string = '\(urlString)'")
} else {
    print("Can't get string from URL")
}

if let queryItems = components.queryItems {
    print("\n---> Query items from components <---\n")
    for (index, queryItem) in queryItems.enumerated() {
        print("queryItem[\(index)] :")
        print("'\(queryItem)'")
    }
}
```

That generates this output:

```
URL string = 
'myApp://home/redirect?Status=Wow&code=200&data=%7B%0A%20%22name%22:%20%22ios%22,%0A%20%22age%22:%2010,%0A%20%7D'

---> Query items from components <---

queryItem[0] :
'Status=Wow'
queryItem[1] :
'code=200'
queryItem[2] :
'data={
 "name": "ios",
 "age": 10,
 }'
```

Note how the URLComponents applies the appropriate escaping to the contents of your "data" query parameter when building an URL string, and also returns an un-escaped JSON string when you fetch the query parameters.

In your app when you parse the incoming URL you should use the above approach to extract the query parameters.

Comment: By the way, there's no real point to adding newline characters to the JSON `data` query parameter. They make the JSON data a little easier to read, but make the URL longer and don't add any benefit. The same goes for spaces outside of quotes. You could shorten your `data` parameter to '"{\"name\":\"ios\",\"age\":10,}"'